# SilverStripe translate fieldlabels

Tags: silverstripe

I simply use `_t()` to translate CMS Fields in a DataObject: `TextField::create('Title', _t('cms.TitleField', 'Title'));`. I thought translating `$summary_fields` was just as simple, but it's not.

Instead of trying to translate Fields and their accompanying summary_fields seperately, I believe I noticed a better way how these fields are translated using the function `FieldLabels` as used in `SiteTree`.

Is there way I can translate these both fields in one place (DRY principle) and apply to both easily by calling the var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I would certainly say the use of `FieldLabels` is for localisation / translation because of the comment "Localize fields (if possible)" [here](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/source-class-SilverStripe.ORM.DataObject.html#3659) in the DataObject code...

```
public function summaryFields() {
     $fields = $this->stat('summary_fields');

     // if fields were passed in numeric array,
     // convert to an associative array
     if($fields && array_key_exists(0, $fields)) {
         $fields = array_combine(array_values($fields), array_values($fields));
     }

     if (!$fields) {
         $fields = array();
         // try to scaffold a couple of usual suspects
         if ($this->hasField('Name')) $fields['Name'] = 'Name';
         if ($this->hasDatabaseField('Title')) $fields['Title'] = 'Title';
         if ($this->hasField('Description')) $fields['Description'] = 'Description';
         if ($this->hasField('FirstName')) $fields['FirstName'] = 'First Name';
     }
     $this->extend("updateSummaryFields", $fields);

     // Final fail-over, just list ID field
     if(!$fields) $fields['ID'] = 'ID';

     // Localize fields (if possible)
     foreach($this->fieldLabels(false) as $name => $label) {
         // only attempt to localize if the label definition is the same as the field name.
         // this will preserve any custom labels set in the summary_fields configuration
         if(isset($fields[$name]) && $name === $fields[$name]) {
             $fields[$name] = $label;
         }
     }

     return $fields;
 }
```

Comment: What an interesting find. I will be spending the next hour re-coding the way I named all fieldnames in my cms.

Comment: I'm going to define a `public function fieldLabels()` in my custom PageType, will the DataObject class pick this up automatically when populating the `summary_fields`?

Comment: the function fieldLabels is looking for the static field_labels to get this information, I would not create that function